# explain mongo faults metric in mongostat

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a question about faults metric in mongostat.
I'm running mongo 2.0, on ubuntu, with 2 disks (each 32G) in raid-0 configuration.

The test in to load into mongo 5 million of user profiles.
I'm doing the process in single thread and use insert (bulk of 1000 entries) .

When I'm setting up the mongo for the **first time** and loading into it the profiles i see many faults in mongostat (2,5,and even 15) during the loading.

Then I'm running the loading again: first i'm dropping the old collection, and then run the loading.
The following times the **faults=0** almost all the time.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB relays memory management to the OS via memory-mapped files mechanism. Basically, this mechanism allows a program to open files much larger than amount of installed RAM. When program tries to access a portion of that file, OS looks if this portion (page) is in RAM. If it is not, then [page fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) happens and that page is loaded from disk. `faults/s` metric in mongostat shows exactly this: how many page faults are occuring per second.

Now, when you're starting mongo and loading data into it, data files are not mapped into memory and they have to be loaded from disk (page faults). When you drop a collection, it is deleted logically, but corresponding physical files are not deleted and will be reused. Since they are in RAM already, there are no page faults.

If you drop a database instead, it takes the files with it, so you should see page faults next time.